# How to see ALT text in Firefox

Tags: firefox

*I know Mozilla thinks it's a bug that IE shows ALT text even after the image has loaded; while users think it's a bug that Firefox doesn't work exactly like IE. This disagreement is irrelevant to my question:*

**How can I make my Firefox show the ALT tooltip when I hover the mouse over an image?**
Obviously [XKCD](http://xkcd.com) is a bit tame without this essential functionality.

I've tried the Firefox plugin [Popup ALT Attribute](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1933/) but it doesn't work; after restarting the browser and hovering over an image with an ALT text, no tooltip appears. I reproduced this on several computers with several (Windows) OS versions.

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem... xkcd has its tooltip jokes - correctly - in the title attribute, which Firefox displays. The alt attribute for xkcd images is simply the title of the comic. (Of course, I can see why you'd want to use it for other sites, but I don't think xkcd is a good example of this issue)

Comment: Thanks for the answers and comments so far! Still, even though you note XKCD uses TITLE tags and not ALT tags, this doesn't work for me using Firefox363 on a freshly installed Win7. How can this be? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There may be an extension on all of these different Firefox installations that is causing this problem (Google toolbar made a similar problem for some users: http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_parentId=383666&forumId=1).  Have you tried hovering over xkcd with a clean Firefox installation without plugins?

Comment: I've disabled all extensions and restarted; still no tooltip appears. I don't have a lot anyway: AdblockPlus, AutoCopy, CopyPlainText, DownloadStatusbar, MinimalistGmail, SearchPreview, Sxipper, Xmarks.

Comment: @torbengb Have you checked that `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips` in `about:config` is set to `true`?

Comment: @sblair: your suggestion about `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips` is most likely the trick! I'll go home and take a look. If you put your comment in an answer, then I can tick it as best answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `alt` text has a [different purpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute#Common_misconceptions) from the `title` text; Firefox (at least, in recent versions) does correctly display the `title` attribute value when the mouse hovers over an image (and it definitely works for xkcd).

**Edit**: in this case, `browser.chrome.toolbar_tips` in [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config) needed to be set to `true`.

Comment: Yes, this fixed it! My Firefox had it set to `false` and toggling it back and forth confirmed this to be the culprit.

Comment: Just a note: at least in Ubuntu, Firefox 11, you need to restart the browser. it was not immediately obvious to me...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your issue is, if I hover over an image in FF it displays the title text.

I'm a regular XKCD reader, that's why I know.

Comment: Not quite, Firefox displays the `title` text in the tooltip.

Comment: You're right, edited answer.